# Uploading Image is not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

I tried this HTML to make a form that allows uploading an image:

```
<!-- Title -->         
<h2 id="cyor-h2">Create your own Recipe</h2>      
<img id="food-image" class="square-recipe-img" style="display:none;" src="no-image.jpg">
<button id="cyor-button" onclick="createButton()">Begin</button> 
    
<!-- Select Image --> 
<button><label for="image_input">Update Image</label></button>
<input style="display:none;" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg,       image/webp" id="image_input">

<script>
let foodImage = document.getElementById("food-image");
let inputFile = document.getElementById("image_input");

inputFile.onchange= myFunction()

function myFunction() {
    foodImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.file[0]);
}
</script>
```

When I try using it, the image doesn't show up. Why not?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `inputFile.onchange= myFunction()`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? What should happen at that point in the code? What will be stored in `inputFile.onchange` afterwards? (Hint: when we write `myFunction()`, what is the purpose of the `()`?) Also: *where* exactly are you expecting the image to be uploaded *to*? Or was that a typo for "update"?

Answer (score 0):

i Hope this helps your cause, for a simple file Upload functionality using js, you can use `FileReader` API in js, and its quite simple. the input fields that you have created is exactly what we are going to use, the only difference is that we are going to introduce a `change` event which changes the src of image from that `img` tag with the one that reader just interpreted.

I wasnt sure what you're gonna do with that  `Begin`button so i deleted it in my code.
Check out the snippet for the implementation.

```js
 const imageInput = document.getElementById("image_input");
        const selectedImage = document.getElementById("selected_image");

        imageInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
            const file = imageInput.files[0];

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    selectedImage.src = e.target.result;
                    selectedImage.style.display = "block";
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                selectedImage.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

```html
<h2>Upload The Recipe</h2>
    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/webp" id="image_input">
    <br>
    <img id="selected_image" style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px; display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems:

`inputFile.onchange = myFunction()` having the parenthesis will make the function get invoked immediately when the script runs but not when the event is invoked. Instead, use this `inputFile.onchange = myFunction` this will allow the function to be invoked when the event occurs.

After fixing the first problem, you need to use the `files` property not `file`. You need to make this modification `foodImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.file[0])`

Make sure you change the `style = display:none` property to something like `block` from `none`. You can do this by adding this within your function like so: `foodImage.style.display = "block";`

using an `addEventListener` instead of `onchange` would be a better option though because in my opinion it makes your code look cleaner but thats just a personal opinion of mine.